# Redshift - Load data which has newline in field

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, etl

I am trying to load the data that includes a new line within a field:

```
001|myname|fav\
movie | myaddress| myphone|
```

There is a blank line between fav\movie.

I am loading the data with this command:

```
COPY catdemo
FROM 's3://tickit/catego.csv'
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::<aws-account-id>:role/<role-name>'
REGION 'ap-south-1'
DELIMITER '|'
ESCAPE
ACCEPTINVCHARS
IGNOREBLANKLINES
NULL AS '\0';
```

I want to ignore this blank line, can anyone help me?

its showing delimiter not found between `fav\ and movie`, but its actually a single line.

> fav\
>
> movie

Comment: What is the copy command you are trying to use?

Comment: copy catdemo
from 's3://tickit/catego.csv'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::<aws-account-id>:role/<role-name>'
region 'us-west-2' removequotes delimiter "|" escape;

Comment: you can use the option  `IGNOREBLANKLINES` see this document for reference. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-ignoreblanklines

Comment: I tried this, but still its not working.

 copy catdemo from 's3://tickit/catego.csv' iam_role  'arn:aws:iam::<aws-account-id>:role/<role-name>' region 'ap-south-1' delimiter '|'  ESCAPE ACCEPTINVCHARS IGNOREBLANKLINES null as '\0';

Comment: where is the blank line anyway? i cannot see a blank line in your example. i see a line split into 2 lines.

Comment: is your copy failing with any error, can you check system load error tables in redshift. ```select filename,colname,type,col_length,raw_field_value,err_reason,err_code from stl_load_errors
where filename like '%filename%' ```

Comment: Its showing delimiter not found,

Comment: Does your data contain null terminated C strings? The way you are specifying your NULL makes me suspect that. Also, would it be possible to quote fields that have newlines? Then you could use the CSV option instead of ESCAPE to solve the problem. Also, if there is a blank line between the words doesn't that mean there are two newline characters there and you would need a backslash before both?